# Bash (split) file name comparison fails

Tags: bash, split, comparison, filenames

In my directory I have files (*fastq.gz.fasta) and directories, whose names contain the filenames (*fastq.gz.fasta-blastdb):

```
IVC6_Meino.clust.gz.fasta-blastdb  
IVC5_Mehiv.clust.gz.fasta-blastdb  
....  
IVC6_Meino.clust.gz.fasta  
IVC5_Mehiv.clust.gz.fasta  
....
```

In a bash script I want to compare the filenames with the direcories using the cut option on the latter to extract only the filename part. If those two names match I want to do further stuff (for now echo match or no match respectively).
I have written the following piece of code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.fasta
do
    for db in *-blastdb
    do
        echo $file, $db | cut -d '-' -f 1
        if [[ $file = "$db | cut -d '-' -f 1" ]]; then
            echo "match"
        else
            echo "no match"
        fi
    done
done
```

But it does not detect matches. The output looks like this:
...

```
IVC6_Meino.clust.gz.fasta, IIIA11_Meova.clust.gz.fasta  
no match  
IVC6_Meino.clust.gz.fasta, IVC5_Mehiv.clust.gz.fasta  
no match  
IVC6_Meino.clust.gz.fasta, IVC6_Meino.clust.gz.fasta  
no match
```

The last line should read match as you can see, the strings look the same.
What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) to do this more easily:

```
for file in *.fasta
do
    for db in *-blastdb
    do
        echo "$file", "$db"         
        if [[ "${file%%.fasta}" = "${db%%.fasta-blastdb}" ]]; then
            echo "match"
        else
            echo "no match"
        fi
    done
done
```

If you want to fix yours, the problem is the use of `$db | cut -d '-' -f 1` With `echo` it *appears* that `echo` is printing the pipe. It isn't. `cut` is printing. When you do `[[ $file = "$db | cut -d '-' -f 1" ]]` it is equivalent to `[[ $file = [return code from last pipe component] ]]`

You need to use the `$(..)` shell construct to capture the output of the pipe and you need to `echo` to get the contents of `$db` to start the pipe. You should quote `"$db"` so you do not have word splitting or globbing from the contents of the variable.

Like so:

```
for file in *.fasta
do
    for db in *-blastdb
    do
        ts=$(echo "$db" | cut -d '-' -f 1)
        echo "$file", "$ts"
        if [[ "$file" = "$ts" ]]; then
            echo "match"
        else
            echo "no match"
        fi
    done
done             # this works I think -- not tested...
```

Please be careful with your quoting with Bash and liberally use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net).

---

The structure you have is also not the most efficient. You will loop over the `*-blastdb` glob once for every file in `*-blastdb`. If you have a lot of files, that could get really slow.

To solve that, you could rewrite this loop with Bash arrays (best if you have Bash 4+) or use `awk`:

```
ext1=.fasta
ext2=.fasta-blastdb
awk  'FNR==NR{
              s=$0
              sub("\\"ext1"$","",s)
              seen[s]=$0
              next}
              {
              s=$0
              sub("\\"ext2"$","",s)
              if (s in seen)
                 print seen[s], $0
              }
              ' ext1="$ext1" ext2="$ext2" <(for fn in *$ext1; do echo "$fn"; done) <(for fn in *$ext2; do echo "$fn"; done)
```

Each glob is only executing once and `awk` is using an array to test if the basenames are the same.

Best